# Push notification opens intent when action button pressed in Marshmallow but not in Jelly Bean

Tags: android, push-notification

I have created a notification push that opens an activity in the app. 
When I press the action button, activity opens correctly, but in devices with Jelly Bean, it doesn't open.

The code to call the notification is this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void createNotificationAPI16(Wifi wifi, Location mCurrentLocation) {

        Drawable myDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Bitmap largeIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, AddWifiActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(AddWifiActivity.SSID, wifi.getWifi_ssid());

        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            resultIntent.putExtra(AddWifiActivity.LATITUDE, mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
            resultIntent.putExtra(AddWifiActivity.LONGITUDE, mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
            resultIntent.putExtra(AddWifiActivity.ZOOM_LEVEL, Constants.ZOOM_LEVEL_BORDER);
        }

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more)
                        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.card_add_wifi_info_message))
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Big Text"))
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_add_wifi, "Text", resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(PushNotifications.NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

What's wrong in the code that doesn´t work with some devices?